# Google UrlShortener 403 Rate Limit Exceeded

Tags: google-api, google-url-shortener

suddenly as of 6pm yesterday I started getting a 403 from Google

```
{
"error": {
    "errors": [
        {
            "domain": "usageLimits",
            "reason": "rateLimitExceeded",
            "message": "Rate Limit Exceeded"
        }
    ],
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Rate Limit Exceeded"
}
```

}

100% of our requests are getting this error. I checked my rates and we are nowhere near the limit. This code has been in place for a year. Any ideas?

- Max for 100s over the last 24 hours is 40
- Total Requests for 24 hours is less than 2000

These are typical rates for us

Comment: We are in "me too" camp. Same issue, looks like started at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had the same issue but it seems to be working now.
The URL shortner API is being deprecated. We had to implement FireBase as well.

Comment: yes this appears to have been a problem on google's end. which has been corrected.

Comment: I don't have an app so firebase is not an option for me

Comment: You can create the app on Firebase's console as iOS and get the ApiKey, it would work to consume their API from a web site or web API. Worked for us.

Comment: @Rogelio I am getting the same error. I checked google url shortener console and it shows maximum 100 requests allowed in 100 second. What should I do to increase that limit? Could you please help how can I move to Firebase API key?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a problem related to Google directly.

We have experienced the same problem during today, and we changed the implementation to FireBase (https://firebase.google.com/). It's not hard to do it.

Note: Google recommends use Firebase because the soon outage of Google URL Shortener.

Comment: Could you please explain how to migrate to firebase from existing google url shortener API?